# How to implement custom fonts in TCPDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, tcpdf

In TCPDF, there are only a few fonts to choose from, to create pdf files. I want to set `Tahoma` as my pdf font. How can I include `Tahoma` in TCPDF??

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The latest TCPDF version automatically convert fonts into TCPDF format using the addTTFfont() method. For example:

```
// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FreeSerifItalic.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

For further information and examples, please check the [TCPDF Fonts documentation page](https://tcpdf.org/docs/fonts/).

NOTE: Once the font has been converted, TCPDF no longer requires the TTF file or the above call to `addTTFfont()`!

Comment: Related Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385618/tcpdf-could-not-include-font-definition-file-with-opentype-fonts/19394545#19394545

Comment: Most likely your call to addTTFfont() can be used with less parameters to let the `addTTFfont()` method automatically detect things: `$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/path-to-font/FreeSerifItalic.ttf');`

Comment: It seems that sometimes `tcpdf` generates wrong `.z` and `.php` files of a font. I tried to use online tool http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf out of another answer to generate .z and .php files and my font is working now.

Comment: Hi @NicolaAsuni Is the tcpdf_addfont.php also possible to use with OTF font? I tried it but it gives me this error message:  '--- Process completed with ERRORS!'

Comment: There is a link at the top of this page that says: "NOTE: The following information is valid only "foR" the old TCPDF library. The new tc-lib-pdf library uses the new tc-lib-pdf-font library that is able to convert fonts on the fly."

Comment: getting error `Class "App\Http\Controllers\TCPDF_FONTS" not found`

Answer (score 30):

I have discovered a very good tool online.
The only thing you need to do is to upload your .ttf file and then download the files and copy then into the /fonts folder.

https://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

Comment: how come this works sometimes but returns empty font definition files the other times?

Comment: FWIW it can happen the other way round too, Anecdotally, I converted the gillsans.ttc into individual TTFs (using [DfontSplitter](https://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter)) but found while TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont worked for semi-bold, bold etc. it returned various errors for the Regular face. The converter at the above URL produced an extra file (gillsans_0.z *and* gillsans_0.z.cpgz) and that displayed correctly. So try both methods.

Comment: I found out that this one: http://fonts.snm-portal.com gives much better results :-)

Comment: For now, this tool doesn't work well with latin-ext fonts from Google Fonts.

Answer (score 10):

The addTTFfont method is not available on TCPDF main class so following worked for me.

```
// convert TTF font to TCPDF format and store it on the fonts folder
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('pathto/arial.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);

// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

the below lines will generate 3 files in ur fonts folder
1.rotisserifi56.php
2.rotisserifi56.ctg
3.rotisserifi56.rar

```
    use this to generate the required php and other files
$fontname = $this->pdf->addTTFfont('D:/wamp/www/projectname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/tcpdf/fonts/Rotis Serif Italic 56.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);

    // use the font
    $this->pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

Now,

use the fonts like this:

```
 $this->pdf->AddFont('rotisserifi56', '', 'rotisserifi56.php');
$this->pdf->SetFont('rotisserifi56');
```

--hope this helps some one :)

Comment: Heh @Developer, it looks like you are using CiviCRM. We're trying to launch a new StackExchange site for CiviCRM at ttp://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm -- we have lots of people interested, but we need another 36 people with 200+ reputation on another StackExchange site to commit before we can launch. Would you help us out? Thanks!

Comment: how you want me to help you?

Comment: Thanks, Developer! Just go to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm and click on Commit button in upper left. If you know of others using CiviCRM encourage them too! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about tcpdf or php, but I found this:

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_033.phps

Apparently you just use the font's name, not the file name.

---

Strike one!

Okay, [how about this page](http://www.tcpdf.org/fonts.php).  To prep a font to be used by TCPDF, you have to run the file through a command line utility and a PHP script.

`$ ttf2ufm -a -F myfont.ttf`

And then:
`$ php -q makefont.php myfont.ttf myfont.ufm`
or
`MakeFont(string $fontfile, string $fmfile [, boolean $embedded [, $enc="cp1252" [, $patch=array()]]])`

ttf2ufm is distributed with TCPDF in the TCPDF/fonts directory.

Answer (score 3):

First create .php ,.afm,.z from http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf and move all three in same directory containing .ttf file.
then Use This :

```
$pdf->AddFont(path-to/universe.ttf','',path-to/universe.php');
$pdf->SetFont(path-to/universe.ttf','',10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the addTTFfont method a little finicky (ok, probably didn't try very hard) and the online tool mentioned above works for FPDF but misses the ctg.z file that TCPDF requires.

This one - http://fonts.snm-portal.com/ - generates the 3 required files (.php, .z and .ctg.z) for TCPDF.  Convert the TTF, upload the three files to your fonts folder and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

Create new font by the following script after adding php in your path

```
php /path_to_tcpdf_directory/tools/tcpdf_addfont.php -i font_name.ttf,font_nameb.ttf,font_namei.ttf
```

Then use the font by following code

```
$pdf->SetFont('Font_name');
```

Name of the font can be found in the /path_to_tcpdf_directory/fonts/font_name.php

To add php into your environment variables, refer [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

Latest TCPDF supports custom fonts.

Documentation about using custom fonts with TCPDF can be read [here](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tc-lib-pdf-font/).

Comment: Link is dead :/

Comment: @Jost thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

the best way i have been tried and worked 100%
   put your `TTF` font in fonts folder and then use this constant `K_PATH_FONTS + FONT NAME`

```
   $font1 = $this->pdf->addTTFfont(K_PATH_FONTS . 'arial.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 8);
   $this->pdf->SetFont($font1, '', 15, '', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using addTTFfont() if you don't have the .ttf file.

And the whole point is: if there is **NO ttf file**, how can someone use addTTFfont() function?

For example, there is no cid0cs file in font/ directory (TCPDF 6.0.20), only cid0cs.php, which is **NOT a font file**.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find addTTFFont() in the latest release of tcpdf.
However, I was able to include a custom TTF file by myself. Within the tcpdf folder is a folder named `tools` which include a PHP file called `tcpdf_addfont.php`.

I symlinked it to my home directory (you can omit this step) and run it like this:
`shell
   ./addfont.php -b -t TrueTypeUnicode -f 32 -i myfont.ttf`

That's it, it will dump something similar to this:
```

> > > Converting fonts for TCPDF:
> > >       *** Output dir set to /Users/pascalraszyk/XXX/XXX/pdf/vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/fonts/
> > >       +++ OK   : /Users/pascalraszyk/XXX/XXX/pdf/myfont.ttf added as myfont
> > >       Process successfully completed!
> > >       ```

**Note:** There are more examples within the `tools` folder for various font types.
I used composer to checkout tcpdf.

As long as you put your font definition files in the `tcpdf/fonts` folder you should be good to go!

I used HTML2PDF which uses tcpdf under the hood and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem despite having all the right files. I had to change the file names to all lower case

Answer (score 0):

**TCPDF: How to add new custom font in tcpdf**

1. Download required font's ttf file
2. Open http://www.fpdf.org/makefont website in the browser and upload the ttf font on this website
3. Download two files `customfontname.php` and `customfontname.z`
4. Copy these two files into `/yourproject/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/` folder
5. include / set the font in your script before tcpdf html code `$pdf->SetFont('customfontname', '', 12);`

Alternate font generation website:
https://fonts.palettize.me

Answer (score -2):

When was not possible convert font GothamRounded standard way, I was looking for another tool and only this one http://fonts.snm-portal.com/ worked for me.

Comment: its a 404 website