# binding font files with PDF document in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

Im scripting to generate a PDF file using TCPDF library, all I want now is to add font files into the document, I could add them using "SetFont" like

```
$pdf->SetFont('myfont', '', 10);
```

and its when I execute this script, the document in browser is rendering fonts perfectly, if I save it and open in another machine then fonts are working with, default fallback font is applying.
I did check it by going to File->Properties->Fonts in Adobe reader, font file is listed there, but text is missing the font.
Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: How are you adding the font files to the script?

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to embed the font using `$pdf->AddFont()`.

A longer description of the differences between `SetFont()`, `AddFont()` and `AddTTFFont()` here:

[TCPDF, "Could not include font definition file" with OpenType fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385618/tcpdf-could-not-include-font-definition-file-with-opentype-fonts/19394545#19394545)