# how to add frutiger lt 55roman font to tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

How to add frutiger lt 55roman font to tcpdf

```
        include ("tcpdf/tcpdf.php");

        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

        $pdf->SetPrintHeader(FALSE);
        $pdf->SetPrintFooter(FALSE);
        //these line i have added in file to include font
        $fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('D:/wamp/www/projectname/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/tcpdf/fonts/Frutiger LT 55 Roman.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
        $pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');

        $html = '<html>
                        <head>
                        <title>Insurance Certificate</title>
                        <style>
                        body{
                            font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        }
                        table{
                        table-layout: fixed;
                        }

                        </style>
                    </head>
                    <body style="-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;">
                        <table border="0px" align=""> 
                            <tr>

                            </tr>                    
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="text-align: left; font-size:14px;"></td>
                                <td width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>                    
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></td>
                               <td width="200px"style="text-align: left; font-size:10px; border-collapse: collapse; border-bottom: 1px solid black; width:400px"><span style="font-size:8px">Mobile Phones, Tablets & Laptops Insurance Cover</span></td>
                                <td width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <br /><br />
                            <tr bgcolor="#EAEBEC"> 
                               <td width="125px"></td>
                               <td width="200px"  height="25px" style="text-align:left" ><b><br /> </td>
                               <td width="200px" style="display:none;" ></td>
                            </tr>
                            <br /><br />
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"  colspan="2" ></td>
                                <td width="300px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: justify; "></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">Name of the Insured in full</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Address for communication</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>                            
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Contact Number & Email ID</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>                    
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; ">Brand & Model of the Device</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Date of Purchase of the Device</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">IMEI / Serial No</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Sum Insured</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Invoice No / Certification No</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Insurance Plans</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>                        
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Coverage Start Date & Time</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Coverage End Date</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Store Code</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"></td>
                                <td width="200px" style="font-size:10px; text-align: left;">Store Name</td>
                                <td style="font-size:10px; text-align: left; font-weight:bold;" width="200px"></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="2px" height="50px" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td width="125px"  style="text-align:center; padding-left:50px;">

                                </td>
                                <td width="400px">
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><img style="margin: 0 0 0 0; width:100px" src="images/edelweiss.png" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                            <td width="20px"></td>
                            <td width="500px"><div style="display: block; overflow: hidden; font-size:8px; width: 100px">         
                            <span><img src="images/spacer.gif" width="10px" height="130px" /></span>
                            <p style="text-align: left; font-weight:bold; padding: 0; margin:0">Terms and Conditions</p>
                            <p style="text-align: left;"><b>Product / Device:</b> 
                            Mobile phone under the scheme of insurance. <br />
                            Value  The value equa on the invoice of Insured Product, bought by the end customer i.e “cost of the product” or “Market value” whichever is lower. Policy will be on agreed value basis subject to maximum of Invoice value.<br />
                            <b></b>: Damage to the Insured Product due to session of the insured person without the person’s consent. Theft will be defined as per relevant sections of the Indian Penal Code and will include but not be limited to burglary, housebreaking, robbery and dacoity. <br />
                            <b></b>: Sudden and accidentaed Product.                   
                            </p>
                            <p style="text-align: left; padding: 0;"><b>Specific Condition </b><br />
                            In the event of any damage which might give rise to a claim under the insurance policy you shall: <br />                     
                               &bull; Notify Insurance Co /Edelweiss within 24 Hours of loss <br />
                               &bull; Take all reasonable steps to minimize the extent of any damage <br />
                               &bull; Preserve damaged parts and make them available for inspection by insurance company representative and/or insurance surveyor and/or authorized representative of service centre of OEM<br />
                               &bull; Provide all information and documentary evidence with respect to the claim as insurer may reasonably require<br />
                                <br />                       
                            <p style="text-align: left; "><b>Depreciation Rates:</b><br />
                            The liability of the Company shall in no case exceed the sum insured subject to the following as per Age of the product / device: <br />
                            &bull;Upto 90 days:10% &bull; 91 to 180 days:15% &bull; 181 to 270 days:20% &bull; 271 to 365 days:25%  &bull; Above 365 days:40%
                            </p>
                      </div></td>

                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>';


        //echo $html;

        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $pdf->lastPage();
        $pdf->Output();
        ?>
```

I wanted to add new font to tcpdf. I used addTTFfont to add a font but it not working.How to add Frutiger LT 55 Roman font to tcpdf ?I did like this...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement custom fonts in TCPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf)

Comment: Not a duplicate. To the other question, the answer is to use `addTTFfont`. OP already did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't enough detail. What does it do instead of working? Is an error produced, either in your output, or in your web server log? How are you running this, stand-alone or through a web server? Can you create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that the function you're having a problem without all the noise around it? If it's not a duplicate, demonstrate HOW.