# custom font not working whmcs

Tags: tcpdf, whmcs-invoice-template

We are trying to add the https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Abel in `WHMCS 7.1.2 invoice pdf`. Initially we have tried with direct font conversion like below and its not working.

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('/templates/six/Abel-Regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
// use the font
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
```

Then we have converted the font into "abel.ctg.z","abel.php", "abel.z"  and uploaded on "`vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts`". Also defined the "`Abel-Regular`" on custom font settings.

Both ways are not working. Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: have you tried this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf ?

Comment: Yes we have tried this and its not working.

Answer (score 2):

After applying the settings, delete the contents of the **templates_c** folder.