# How to show different language on PDF file using tcpdf?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

I am generating a pdf file from the MySQL database table data. In this database table, there can be multiple language data/string. For example, English, Spanish, German, Bangla language etc..

Now when I create a PDF file based on MySQL table data it's contain something like that string !!

[image]

But the original string is :

[image]

I am using tcpdf and calling following class:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Try this http://www.xml-convert.com/en/convert-tff-font-to-afm-pfa-fpdf-tcpdf

Comment: let me try with this

Comment: @Athi not working, still showing the strange characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf