# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method TCPDF::addTTFfont() in C\... Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need to add Custom font using TCPDF. I followed the procedure as mentioned in TCPDF documentation like Conversion of TTFont to TCPDF fonts  & add it fonts folder & define font in tcpdfconfig_fonts.php, & tried to call that function. This error is thrown.Though TCPDF has a function addTTFont, it is throwing error as Call to Undefined font Can anyone suggest me, whats wrong

Thanks in advance

Comment: _Show us your code..._ After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement custom fonts in TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf)