# Is there any way to use font face as inline in HTML tag?

Tags: php, tcpdf

**Is there any way to use font-face as inline in HTML tag?**
I am trying to use Urdu language fonts in the TCPDF PHP library as an inline.

```
$pdf->WriteHTMLCell(195, 0, '', '', '<h1 style="text-align:center; color:#007348; font-family:JameelNooriKasheeda">' . $urdu . '</h1>', 0, 1);
```

Comment: No, you must "prepare" TCPDF to accept a new font not included in "CoreFonts". First of all, download .ttf file of your desired font, then.. you can follow the instructions from tcpdf author here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263588/how-to-implement-custom-fonts-in-tcpdf