# Set PHP environment variable (XAMP)

Tags: php, environment-variables

I want to set PHP environment variable.

I tried this solution from [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

> You need to put the directory that has php.exe in you WAMP installation into your PATH. It is usually something like `C:\wamp\xampp\php`

I put `PATH=C:\xampp\php` in path. Now what to do next?

When I execute `php array.php` it says `Could not open input file:array.php`.

Comment: Do not pay attention to the accepted answer. Look for the one with the most points. The answer with 8 points is the one you need to look at.

Answer (score 3):

In command prompt

`SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php`

OR

in windows 7

**right click on my computer -> properties ->Advanced System Settings(On left side bar) -> select Advanced tab ->Environment Variables -> From System variable select Path and edit(*Don't press new*) -> put a `;` at the end and then `php.exe` path paste it there.**

and you've done

Comment: i did it.Now when try to to execute php array.php then its says could not open input file

Comment: e.g there is only one line echo "hello" but still its says could not open input file when i execute php hello.php from cmd

Comment: Where you're placing the `.php` file and what is your url for the access ?

Comment: can you show me the exact error you're getting from the browser ?

Comment: If i run this in browser then its works fine but when i execute it in cmd then it says "Could not open input file".

Comment: You may not have permission to r/w/x on that file