# No php executable defined eclipse-symfony

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony

I'm tring to create a new symfony project but at creation eclipse show me an error:

```
  No PHP executable defined. Please specify a valid executable in the PHP Executables preference page.
```

I have already defined in preference -> php executables : XDebug but the error appear.

Comment: Have you defined /usr/bin/php, and What linux distribution do you use?

Comment: How can I define /usr/bin/php ? I'm using windows 7 @twicejr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick workaround for fix this issue is remove all php binaries listed and use the "Search" button using only paths where the binaries are stored, for example in Ubuntu or Debian /usr/bin

That will find the links to php binary paths (with some loop, so you have to unselect all and select only one).

You can find [more detailed info about this bug](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/issues/186) in Github issue tracker for the project

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to :

1) Using a server emulation like xampp : https://www.apachefriends.org/

2) Finding your PHP executable in XAMPP and add it in your eclipse PHP executable

3) Setting PHP in your variable environment path : [How to set the env variable for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try delete all manually added paths and use search button in the PHP executable preference dialog. Then you should set main path of your Xampp installation eg.: D:\PROGRAM FILES\xampp. 
Don't set subpaths like eg.: D:\PROGRAM FILES\xampp\php. In my case it causes "No PHP executable defined..." error.