# Can't install composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Hello I'm having trouble using Composer.
I'm using xampp on Windows 7 and I used the Composer Installer. When it asked me to select my php.exe I selected the one in xampp PHP folder. I'm not sure if I should've done that.

So. Now when I try to use the "composer" command line in my CMD it gives me error as 
'php' isn't recogonized as a command. (Sorry if that is not correctly translated)

Anyone knows how to fix it ? Should I remove and re-install composer ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I just had to set my PHP folder in %PATH%
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\wamp\path\php