# How to use yii2 sub-commands with git bash?

Tags: bash, yii2, git-bash

I try to create new table using yii2 migration:

```
php yii migrate/create create_new_table
```

When I use cmd everything is ok, but when I try do the same thing with git bash:

```
Error: Unknown command "migrate\create".
```

P.S. "php yii migrate" works OK.

Comment: Please let me know what is your OS(Linux/Windows/MAC)?

Comment: @Sajjad_Dehghani OS Windows 10

Comment: Just insert your php.exe complete path like: `C:\xampp\php\php.exe yii migrate/create create_new_table `

Comment: It works! But why?

Comment: I write answer, Please don't forget mark currect answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert your php.exe complete path like:

`C:\xampp\php\php.exe yii migrate/create create_new_table`

If you don't want to write always complete php path, Set php.exe path on windows Env:

[refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)

[refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1)