# phpinfo() and laravel installation through composer both are showing diffrent version of php

Tags: laravel-5, php

I'm facing this issue. I have a problem that

> phpinfo() shows me 5.5.11 version is installed.

But while installing laravel 5.2 through composer it showing me following error,

> [InvalidArgumentException]  Could not find package laravel/laravel
>   with version 5.2.* in a version installable using your PHP version
>   5.5.8.

Laravel 5.2 needs,

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension

Both are working properly. And My current version is 5.5.11 which is >= 5.5.9 so what is the error. I can't figure it out.

**EDIT :-**
I have already set environment variable like this,

> PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php.

php.exe file in this path in my windows.

Comment: Make sure to set your PHP Environment variable correctly. It has different syntax depending on your OS. 
More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php

Comment: @Mithredate. I have updated my question with your suggestion please check it.

Answer (score 0):

plz check your local path , copy your php environment path.
and open the floder with the path, check the php version in this path.

seems you should have differet php version.