# Php5 to php7 update not working

Tags: php, iis, installation

My current version of PHP is 5, I download the version 7 and installed it, I am using IIS server.

Here is my ISS manager:

[image: phpinfo()]

It says that the version of PHP is 7.1.6, but when I run a PHP version check in the command line it gave me this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 18.8.15863] (c) 2817 microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved . 
C:\Users\marvenwi1sons>php --version 
PHP S. 3.5 (cli) (built: Jan S 2811 Copyright (c) 1997-2818 The PHP Group 
Zend Engine v2 .3 . 8, Copyright (c) 1998-2818 Zend Technologies 
C:\Users\marvenwi1sons>
```

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Download php7 as zip
2. Make new folder named “php” to C > programfiles
3. Extract the downloaded php7 zip file to “php” folder
4. In IIS manager I clicked PHP Manager
5. Then I Clicked “Register new PHP version”
6. Then I navigate to “php” folder and clicked “php-cgi.exe”
7. Then I check php info and restart the IIS then restart my computer

Comment: did you restart IIS just after your installation?

Comment: You most likely have a leftover system file pointing to the older install.

Comment: @LukasMeine yes, I restarted it,, and even restarted my computer,

Answer (score 2):

> When you run phpinfo and it is running fine ,then you have your php
>   application working fine in IIS.

I guess What is not running for you is the php command from Windows Command line, it looks in the Path variables to find where the command executable is . To find where it picks up the command line,you can run the command **where**

e.g for node

```
C:\Users\Rohit>where node
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

So you can run where and find out where your php.exe is . This path would have added to your [path](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

You can also run following command to print this in windows

```
C:\Users\Rohit>echo %Path%
```

You have to edit the path to point to where your php7 resides (installed in your machine).[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736528/how-to-set-the-env-variable-for-php)   and this [article](https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/) has instructions to do this

Comment: It is very likely that the %path% variable still points to the old PHP installation. PHP Manager won't change that, and the user is expected to remove the old folder from %path% and add the new folder instead.