# How to execute PHP globally on Windows CMD

Tags: php, cmd, command-line-interface

Hi I want to execute a PHP file under windows CMD  with PHP CLI server

on linux i am doing something like that :

on my `/usr/local/bin` I have a file called `Jimboo`

that file contains the following

```
 #!/usr/bin/php
 <?php
 require "/var/www/jimboo/run/index.php";
```

so on my terminal i just type `Jimboo` and my php application fire sup

so how can i do something similar to this ? how can i use custom global command to run my app on CMD

note : i can do `php link to my index.php` but this is not so practical . thanks

Comment: Define path of php executable file as windows environment variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/2736574/853360

Comment: Create a batch file and add it to your path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run php globally, make sure you have the `php cli` set up properly in the environment variables.

if you wish to make it as simple as entering the name and accessing it, and want to try something a bit different as mentioned in the other answer, do this.

Compile this program in c++ to make an executable `Jimboo.exe` and add the location of `Jimboo.exe` to your **PATH**. Then only typing in **`Jimboo`** in cmd will execute the command.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Running Jimboo";
    system("php yourPHPfile.php argument1 argument2 ... ");
}
```

make sure you add php to PATH before using the above code.

Comment: thank you so much that's what i was thinking about :)

Comment: Cheers! Glad to know that! That's the core of programming. Use code to simplify life.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support the `shebang` syntax like Linux does.

To configure the `.php` file extension association to open with the PHP executable.

1. right click a `.php` file (or any file extension you want to associate with php.exe)
2. click `Open With`
3. Select `More Apps`
4. scroll to the bottom `Choose another app`
5. Select `Look for another app on this PC`
6. Navigate to the `php.exe` executable and select it
7. Check the `Always use this app to open .php files`
8. click Ok

Afterward you can open up a command prompt (`cmd`) and have php execute `.php` files by path without needing to prefix php.

You can also execute a `.php` file by double clicking them (though the PHP terminal will not stay opened after executing unless you add `sleep` just like a `.bat` file functions).

> I used `.php3` as an example since I have `.php` configured to open
>   with my IDE.

**d:\test.php3**

```php
<?php

echo 'Hello World';
```

To make the `.php` file extension an executable like in linux with `chmod 0111`. You would have to append `;.PHP` to the `PATHEXT` Windows Environment Variable.

[image: PATHEXT]

To make it the file globally accessible, append the directory the `.php` file is located in to your `PATH` Windows Environment Variable. Otherwise move the `.php` file to a directory already listed in your `PATH` Windows Environment Variable, such as `C:\Windows` or `C:\Windows\System32`

To initialize the new environment variable, either launch a new command prompt (`cmd`) as Administrator and close it or reboot.

[image: cmd php]

---

Alternatively create a `C:\Windows\Jimboo.bat` file that contains.

```
@echo off
"X:\path\to\php.exe" "X:\path\to\index.php"
```

This will then execute the desired file in a command prompt by typing `Jimboo`.

[image: Batch File PHP]